# RDP to win 11 with Remina single display unless root

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, wayland, remmina

Build: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 2x 1920x1080 Monitors

Symptom: Launching Remmina 1.4.25 without sudo privileges maximizes full screen at a single monitor with redirected audio.  Launching with SUDO via terminal allows for simple multi display, but no redirected audio.

I've seen various mutters and similar posts, but most focus on Remina RDP to another instance of Ubuntu using protocols other than Free RDP.

Request:  A fix in the config to either get redirected audio to work with elevated permissions, or more desirably, a workaround / fix to the Wayland+Remmina multi display issue.